# Greying of answers

Tags: support

I've noticed that in several places answers have been greyed out. [Here's an example](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2322/19894):

[image]

Here, it is quite clear that the lower answer is lighter than the upper answer. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers of score -3 or lower are greyed out, by design.